# Google Map (API ) Pricing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We want to develop a Vehicle Tracking System. We are designing a software using Python-Django and JavaScript Template. We are using google map. But it is free of cost. With the help if gmplot python package I am able to generate location on google map. If I want to further extend it to source and destination track information. Will it cost and if it is then on what basis? I have checked the Google API on google developers site. But not able to understand the pricing plans. Can you provide simple explanation about using google maps in our web applications?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is against the Google Maps API terms of user to use it for vehicle tracking applications without purchasing the license from Google. Search "fleet management" at below link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions